# Firestore array is saved with wrong elements order

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

UPDATE: Google support acknowledged this is a bug and are working on resolving this.

I'm testing Firestore on node (v8.9.4 on Windows) and see a weird problem - when I'm saving an array with long strings the order of the elements in Firestore is different from the original array. Take a look at the code below:

```js
var result_data = [
    (new Array(100*1000)).join("a"),
    (new Array(100*1000)).join("b"),
    (new Array(100*1000)).join("c"),
    (new Array(2)).join("d")
];

// console.log(result_data);
var data_collection = db.collection('sources').doc(doc.id).collection('data');
data_collection.add({
    time: new Date(),
    data: result_data
});
```

As you can see, the above should save an array of 4 elements, first 3 elements with length of 99,999 and the last element of length 1. This is what I see instead in Firestore admin (and the same if I read the data myself) - the short element moved to the first position:

[image: Last element moved to the first position]

Can anyone shed some light on this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add an example of your data?  Which client SDK and version are you using? I just tried writing an array to a document and ordered them in a particular way.  That order was preserved (Firebase Admin Node.js SDK v5.9.1).

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, @JasonBerryman! It works for me as well when I'm saving a simple array with short values. The problem seems to happen only with particularly large values. Let me try to isolate the problem and post a working code sample.

Comment: @JasonBerryman - I've added an isolated example.